# vb.net multiple search statements in one subroutine

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, using

I have 5 Select Statements that search the SQLite Database the search variables are built on
a Form called frmBuildSearches and passed to a form with a DataGridView
The issue I am trying to overcome is I need to have 5 Sub Routines for each Search Type that is built
I would like to put the 5 Search Statements in ONE Sub Routine and when that Sub Routine is called make a decision
which Search Statement will be used. This is my first time working with the **"Using"** statement
This is were the challenge starts and after a lot of trial and error has stopped
The code below is one Sub Routine with 4 of the Search Statements commented out
Question How to embed the Search Statements in one Sub Routine with the "Using" statement ?

```
    Private Sub MoRangeYr()
    Dim intID As Integer
    Dim strDate As String
    Dim strTxType As String
    Dim strAmt As Decimal
    Dim strCKNum As String
    Dim strDesc As String
    Dim strBal As Decimal
    Dim rowCount As Integer
    Dim maxRowCount As Integer
    Dim emptyStr As String = "  "

    Using conn As New SQLiteConnection($"Data Source = '{gv_dbName}';Version=3;")
        conn.Open()
        '========================
        'Designed Searches Below
        'All
        'Using cmd As SQLiteCommand = New SQLiteCommand($"SELECT * FROM TxData", conn)
        'MoYr
        'Using cmd As SQLiteCommand = New SQLiteCommand($"SELECT * FROM TxData WHERE txSearchMonth = '{gvFromMonth}' AND txYear = '{gvYear}' ", conn)
        'TxMoYr
        'Using cmd As SQLiteCommand = New SQLiteCommand($"SELECT * FROM TxData WHERE txType = '{gvTxType}' AND txSearchMonth = '{gvFromMonth}'AND txYear = '{gvYear}' ", conn)
        'Year
        'Using cmd As SQLiteCommand = New SQLiteCommand($"SELECT * FROM TxData WHERE txYear = '{gvYear}' ", conn)
        '=========================
        'MoRangeYr
        Using cmd As SQLiteCommand = New SQLiteCommand($"SELECT * FROM TxData WHERE  txSearchMonth = '{gvFromMonth}' AND txSearchMonth = '{gvToMonth}' AND txYear = '{gvYear}' ", conn)

            Using rdr As SQLite.SQLiteDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

                While rdr.Read()
                    intID = CInt((rdr("TID")))
                    strDate = rdr("txSortDate").ToString
                    strTxType = rdr("txType").ToString
                    strAmt = CDec(rdr("txAmount"))
                    strCKNum = rdr("txCKNum").ToString
                    strDesc = rdr("txDesc").ToString
                    strBal = CDec(rdr("txBalance"))
                    dgvTX.Columns(3).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N"
                    dgvTX.Columns(6).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N"
                    'dgvTX.Columns(6).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "C"'Adds the $ sign and commas
                    dgvTX.Rows.Add(intID, strDate, strTxType, strAmt, strCKNum, strDesc, strBal, emptyStr)
                    Dim dateToday = Date.Today


                    Dim lblDate As String = dateToday.ToString("MMM" & " " & "d" & " " & "yyyy")
                    lblAmt.Text = "Current Balance  " & lblDate
                    tbBal.Text = "$ " & String.Format("{0:n}", strBal)
                    rowCount = rowCount + 1
                End While

                dgvTX.Sort(dgvTX.Columns(0), ListSortDirection.Descending)
                If rowCount <= 25 Then
                    maxRowCount = 25 - rowCount
                    For iA = 1 To maxRowCount
                        dgvTX.Rows.Add(" ")
                    Next
                End If
                rdr.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
        conn.Close()
    End Using
    tbBal.Focus()

End Sub
```

This code decides which Sub Routing is used

```
    Private Sub frmViewTX_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    StyleDGV()

    If gvTEST Is "All" Then
        PopulateDGV()
    ElseIf gvTEST Is "MoYr" Then
        JustOne()
    ElseIf gvTEST Is "Year" Then
        YearOnly()
    ElseIf gvTEST Is "TxMoYr" Then
        TxMoYr()
    ElseIf gvTEST Is "MoRangeYr" Then
        MoRangeYr()
    End If
    'MoRangeYr
End Sub
```

Comment: Parameterize your queries! Using string manipulation to put your data into SQL is how you find out next year you were hacked six months ago.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I kind of get that but I am SELECTING data It was INSERTED to prevent that

Comment: Doesn't matter. I can still use injection to insert data, even when you're trying to run a SELECT query.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn like this Using con As New MySqlConnection(strConnect) It is from Code Project

Comment: What will determine which query runs?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I added the code which is in the Form Load that determines which query runs NOT pretty but functional

Comment: Declare a string variable to hold the SQL command text (Dim sqlText as String), then do your decision tree to workout which command to run, and then you just feed it into  Using cmd As SQLiteCommand = New SQLiteCommand(sqlText)

Comment: That said, if your query has different uses, I would be more incline to do specific functions with or without overloads.

Comment: @Hursey I tried that and have used that in the DARK AGES of VB6 the issue is that "$" does not like being in the string with the SELECT statement I have been trying to write the statement as a STRING still trying

Comment: @Vector When a commenter with 368K reputation points tells you to use parameters, just take it on faith. You will learn later why.

Comment: @Mary I agree ESPECIALLY when they teach for a living Hope you are still playing Bridge Nice to see you here My Check Book application almost done Need to find a new project that has NEW challenges

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I've said already, make sure to use parameterized queries! That out of the way, the basic answer to the question is you can change the `CommandText` property between when you create the `SQLiteCommand` object and when you actually run the command:

```
Private Sub MoRangeYr()
 
    Using conn As New SQLiteConnection($"Data Source = '{gv_dbName}';Version=3;")
    Using cmd As New SQLiteCommand("",conn)
        
        If gvTEST = "ALL" Then
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TxData"
        Else If gvTEST = "MoYr" Then
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TxData WHERE txSearchMonth = $gvFromMonth' AND txYear = $gvYear " 
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("$gvFromMonth", gvFromMonth)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("$gvYear", gvYear)
        Else If gvTEST = "TxMoYr" Then
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TxData WHERE txType = $gvTxType AND txSearchMonth = $gvFromMonth AND txYear = $gvYear "
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("$gvTxType", gvTxType)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("$gvFromMonth", gvFromMonth)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("$gvYear", gvYear)
        Else If gvTEST = "MoRangeYr" Then
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TxData WHERE txYear = $gvYear "
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("$gvYear", gvYear)
        End If   

        conn.Open()
        Using rdr As SQLite.SQLiteDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            dgvTX.DataSource = rdr

             dgvTX.Columns(3).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N"
             dgvTX.Columns(6).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N"
        End Using

        lblAmt.Text = $"Current Balance  {DateTime.Today:MMMM d yyyy}"
        ' tbBal.Text = "${strBal:n}" ' This was wrong in the original code

        dgvTX.Sort(dgvTX.Columns(0), ListSortDirection.Descending)

    End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

You may also want to look into DataBinding this result. You're writing a lot of extra code to do work the GridView knows how to do for you. One more thing: instead of `dgvTX.Sort()` at the end, try adding an `ORDER BY` to the SQL that gives you that order in the first place.

Comment: I am working on using DataBinding but started with Styling the DGV Thanks for the Education I hope your students enjoy your teaching and knowledge base